# Pe file import binding

Tags: windows, pe, import-reconstruction

I'm learning a bit about `PE files`. The thing I've struggling a bit now it the `First Thunk` and `Original First Thunk` fields. To understand the difference between them I've read this post and that article. To test the problem "live" I've opened said `shell32.dll` or `notepad.exe` files in `PE-bear` and `IDA` BUT that appears the there is NO `import binding` in case of that files in contrast to what the articles say. Here are my question now:

Why there is NO `import binding` in these files?

Here are the [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42413937/why-pe-need-original-first-thunkoft) and the [second](https://web.archive.org/web/20180103163005/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100318-00/?p=14563) article.

Please don't down-vote the question if it appears to lame because I'm just newbie in the topic.

Comment: there's absolutely no article

Comment: @mimak I've added the links now.

Comment: @Robert I've added the links now.

Comment: @mimak Are You alive!? Can You try to answer the question now?

Comment: @Robert Are You alive!? Can You try to answer the question now?